# Azure Vnet: Control traffic to fqdn without Azure Firewall

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have created a vnet on Microsoft azure for development purposes. The vnet is divided into subnets as per development, i.e., backend, frontend, or database.

Can anyone please help me understand how I can control outbound traffic from VM so that the VM can only send traffic as per the development requirement? For example, the VM in the frontend subnet should only send traffic to angular.js CDN and nowhere else; similarly, VM in the backend should only send traffic to the maven repository.

I know this can be achieved using an azure firewall, but as my team is small and VMs are not used 24hrs, the firewall is a too expensive option for me

Comment: It really doesn't sound like you *NEED* a (paid, expensive) Azure Firewall.  Please investigate [NSGs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-security-groups-overview).  See also [Azure network security overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/fundamentals/network-overview)

Comment: Your VM needs to be able to connect with many resources, both inside Azure and outside. Updates, patches, licensing, monitoring, logging, authorization, etc. Restricting egress traffic is problematic at best.

Comment: My whole infrastructure is based on Azure, and Virtual Machines are also running on Windows OS. Suppose I don't restrict egress traffic. The developers may send traffic to sites unrelated to their work or even share code through file-sharing services like one drive or google drive. To avoid these scenarios, will it be better if I just allow egress traffic to azure resources and selected domain names(like cdnjs.cloudflare.com, mvnrepository.com).

Comment: I thought of using NSG for this, but in NSG, I can only specify IP Address and not the domain name, and since for development, I will be working using CDN, the IP address may change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to be able to control traffic based on FQDN/destination domain. I'm going to go with the assumption that your main concern is cost, hence you would probably need to build an IaaS-based solution yourself, or get one from the Azure Marketplace.

You could setup an open source forwarding proxy like [Squid Proxy](http://www.squid-cache.org/) on a B1ls/B1s Linux VM, which is relatively easy to setup and very cheap. You'd then forward all requests to Squid and manage an allow/deny list on Squid. However, proxies generally have limited support for HTTPS.

You would need a solution that can also intercept/decrypt your traffic to identify the FQDN the machine is attempting to connect to. Fortunately Squid proxy v3.5 and above has [SslBump Peek and Splice](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslPeekAndSplice) that might help with this.

Now in the event the above doesn't work for you, you might want to explore an Open Source firewall like [pfsense](https://www.pfsense.org/), which you could again just install on a VM.

The advantage you get with an IaaS solution like the two above is that you can shut them down when not in use - following a similar schedule as your application VMs, bring the overall cost even further down.

Comment: Hi Ked, Do  you have any documentation that informs how to deny all outbound traffic on pfSense and only allow traffic to a specific domain